# Output multiple elements as a JSON array in XSLT

Tags: json, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XSL Code as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="inlineAddressArray">
    <addrline>Home1</addrline>
    <addrline>Home2</addrline>
    <addrline>Home3</addrline>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" name="data" select="exsl:node-set($inlineAddreddArray)" />

  <addressLines>
    <xsl:value-of select="$data/addrline" />
  </addressLines>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected JSON output should be:

```
"addressLines":"[Home1,Home2,Home3]"
```

Output that I'm getting

```
"addressLines": "Home1Home2Home3"
```

Basically it is just concatenating every element as a single element.

But, I should get three elements separately as shown above.

Can anyone please help me on this? Don't mind if it's a silly query. I'm very new to XSLT :)

Comment: Why is your question tagged `xslt-2.0` when you are obviously using (or rather misusing) XSLT 1.0? And what is the point of defining a variable with hard-coded elements, when you need a string?

Comment: @michael.hor257k- Yes, I'm using XSLT 2.0. And the values present inside my request are string type. For easy understanding I've hardcoded in the question.

Comment: There is no need to use `exsl:node-set()` in XSLT 2.0. And your output is XML, not JSON, so it's not clear how JSON comes into this at all.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, the "expected JSON" `"addressLines":"[Home1,Home2,Home3]"` doesn't look like JSON. Also, your XSLT outputs XML, do you integrate XSLT in some other tool chain where that XML is being converted to JSON? In that case you need to name the tool chain.

Comment: @MartinHonnen -  yes that's correct. I'm converting XML to JSON via Newtonsoft. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode() function to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No need for Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode() .**

**Given this xml:**

```
<inlineAddressArray>
  <addrline>Home1</addrline>
  <addrline>Home2</addrline>
  <addrline>Home3</addrline>
</inlineAddressArray>
```

**Using this xslt 2.0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"  encoding="UTF-8" />
  
  <xsl:template match="inlineAddressArray">
    <xsl:text>"addressLines":"[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="addrline" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>]"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**or using xslt 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"  encoding="UTF-8" />
  
  <xsl:template match="inlineAddressArray">
    <xsl:text>"addressLines":"[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="addrline"/>
    <xsl:text>]"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="addrline">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**results in this :**

```
"addressLines":"[Home1,Home2,Home3]"
```

**UPDATE**

if you also want to deal with empty addrline like i.e.

```
<inlineAddressArray>
  <addrline>Home1</addrline>
  <addrline>Home2</addrline>
  <addrline></addrline>
</inlineAddressArray>
```

**Your xslt 1.0 could look like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"  encoding="UTF-8" />
  
  <xsl:template match="inlineAddressArray">
    <xsl:text>"addressLines":"[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="addrline"/>
    <xsl:text>]"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="addrline">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test=" following-sibling::addrline[(normalize-space(.))]">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="addrline[not(normalize-space(.))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I'm getting separator attribute is not declared issue. Could you help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure your processor support xslt 2.0?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works like a charm using XSLT 1.0 code. But I have a scenario where if one of the elements doesn't have any value, it shouldn't be populating an empty string. For example let's say I have 

`<inlineAddressArray>
  <addrline>Home1</addrline>
  <addrline>Home2</addrline>
  <addrline></addrline>
</inlineAddressArray>`

My output should be `["Home1","Home2"]`

Could you please tell me how can I make this work?